# Is it ok to repeatedly add event listener in the event pages for chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am learning the Event Pages for Chrome extension and according to the documentation, the scripts will only be loaded when needed. Then I find that the [Google Mail Checker](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/extensions/gmail/)'s event page script will add the event listener:

```
// Some declarations

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(goToInbox);

// ...
```

And I write an event script:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: 'https://www.google.com'});

function onClickListener() {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: 'https://www.bing.com'});
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(onClickListener);
```

After I reloaded my extension, a new tab of google.com is opened as expected. Seconds later the process of my extension is gone in Chrome's task manager, and I clicked the extension icon. Then, both google.com and bing.com are opened! So I learn that this entire script will be loaded again.

Now look back to the script of Google Mail Checker. The listener will be added repeatedly once the script is loaded, so my question is: is it ok to add listener repeatedly? If the listener's behavior will change from A to B when the script is loaded, which one will be fired on the second load, A or B?

Answer (score 1):

In fact your question is logically impossible, since the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#registration) has stated that the event listener will only exist in the context of the event page, that means it will be automatically removed once the event page is unloaded. So to some degree, it's ok to add listener repeatedly, although in fact you are adding it only once.

> **Because the listeners themselves only exist in the context of the event page, you must use addListener each time the event page loads**

And Chrome also states that in the first line of [best practices when using event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#best-practices)

> **Register to receive any events your extension is interested in each time the event page is loaded.** The event page will be loaded once for each new version of your extension. After that it will only be loaded to deliver events you have registered for. This generally means that your event listeners should be added at the top level scope of the event page, otherwise they may not be available when the event page reloads.

Comment: If all listeners are destroyed, how does chrome know when the script should be reloaded? I guess that chrome has a list of events registered by an extension, and when an event is fired, chrome reloads the script and call the event listener if it exists.